# AngularJS - Two way binding an span

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text object and I want to bind it to an editable span, since AngularJS provides two-way binding to inputs, but not to spans, I thought just catching the key events and updating the model would be easy.
Here is my model:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("TextController", function ($scope, $http, $location, $interval) {
        $scope.myText = "my text";
        $scope.updateModel = function () {
            $scope.myText = $("#myspan").html();
        };
        ...
    });
```

Here is my span:

```
<span id="myspan" contenteditable="true" ng-keyup="updateModel()" ng-bind="myText"></span>
```

I'm catching the keyup events and updating the model, however all sorts of weird things happens with the cursor (will jump to the beginning).
Is there an elegant way to do this?
Should I just use input or textarea? I know using span is unorthodox, but seems to work fine in google docs.

Comment: I would not recommend an editable span. Can a css-modified input/textarea support your feature?

Comment: I would recommend using an input here - you can use CSS to style it to look any way you'd like at this point, so the actual HTML element shouldn't make a difference unless there was another reason you are specifically wanting to use a span?

Comment: @aegrey, that's what I was thinking, though if you inspect google docs or some other web editors they use spans or even divs, they resize themselves to the content and apparently it's not an easy task to do with textareas (and CSS only).

Answer (score 0):

Please find below snippet for your answer:

In here, you're including jQuery and I would recommend to use angular functionality itself like below .

Mostly we use input tag with ng-model for two way data binding in AngularJS.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("TextController", function($scope, $http, $location, $interval) {
    $scope.myText = "my text";
    $scope.updateModel = function() {
      $scope.myText = 'abc';
    };
  $scope.myValue = 'First value'
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TextController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <label>Span Value: </label>
    <span id="myspan" contenteditable="true" ng-keyup="updateModel()" ng-bind="myText"></span><br><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="myValue" ng-model="myValue" ><br><br>
    {{myValue}}
  </body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps you.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks varit05, though I don't see how this solves the two-way binding of a span. Two-way binding of the input[text] it's pretty straight forward. But if I type something on the span it would override it with "abc", and I lost binding to the model, right?

Comment: Yes @JulianB. two way data-binding with `ng-bind` isn't look good. so I have provide the `input` example with `ng-model` which provides two way data binding. If I were you. I would use input,select, textarea for two way data binding.